# Проблема со скачиванием веб страницы

Tags: url, jsoup, java-8

требуется получить информацию со страницы "https://www.fonbet.ru/#!/bets/football", но у меня всё это дело никак не получается. Т.е. получается, но таблица матчей не считывается. Пробовал использовать Jsoup

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.fonbet.ru/#!/bets/football").get();
String text = doc.body().text();
```

И так же пробовал через URL

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.fonbet.ru/#!/bets/football");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(url.openConnection().getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    while (true) {
        String line = reader.readLine();
        if (line == null)
            break;
```

Прошу совета от вас. Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Добро пожаловать в Web 2.0, где данные чаще подгружаются javascript'ом, чем в разметке.

Comment: Если подгрузка делается скриптами, то скорее всего через ajax. Вы можете через панель разработчика браузера (F12) на вкладке сети посмотреть какой запрос посылаются для получения таблицы и самому его вызвать

Comment: Посмотрел какие запросы на том сайте ходят и самый жирный (1.24 мб) имеет кучу интересных данных в JSON. Скорее всего там и будет информация из таблицы: https://line31.bkfon-resource.ru/line/currentLine/ru/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что твой сайт написан на реакте. Просто загрузить такую страницу недостаточно, т.к. на загруженной странице есть js код, который должен выполнится на стороне клиента и загрузить таблицу.

Варианты реализации твоей задачи:

1. Эмулировать веб клиент (например с помощью [selenium webdriver](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) или [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/))
2. Выполнить js код напрямую из java кода (с этим может справится, к примеру [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino))